# Is “He was eating.” a complete sentence to a question?

Tags: sentence-construction, responses

Is “He was eating.” a complete sentence to the question “What is Stacey eating?”

Comment: It is a grammatically complete *sentence* but not a logical *answer*.

Comment: What was Stacey doing? She was eating.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks what Stacy is eating, not if Stacy is eating. A response would specify the kind of food that Stacy is eating. It would also use the female pronoun "she" if Stacy is female.